# Properties of two operators of projection

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, projection

a)Prove that if two operators commute then they composition is operator of projection

b)Prove that in opposite way that is not true

for a)

Let $E=U_1\oplus W1=U_2\oplus W_2$, if $P_1$ is projection on $U_1$ along $W_1$, and $P_2$ is projection on $U_2$ along $W_2$. If $P_1P_2=P_2P_1$, then $(P_1P_2)^2=P_1P_2P_1P_2=P_1P_1P_2P_2=P_1^2P_2^2=P_1P_2$, so it is operator of projection the same is for $P_2P_1$.

b) I think that if $U_1 \subset W_2$ and $U_2\not \subset W_1$, but then  $P_2P_1=(P_2P_1)^2 $ but  $P_2P_1\not=P_1P_2$

Comment: Something is wrong. In a), you should require that the two commuting operators are projections themselves.

Comment: can you write, how i should write I know what you say but i do not know how to write

Comment: "Prove that, if two **projection** operators commute, then they composition is a projection operator".

Comment: I get a question like that i write so i just write how my professor ask me